# Assistance building a regex for a String

Tags: java, regex, math

I'm making a Equation resolver using Quadratic formula, so i pass all data using an Scanner

What i want to do is the next thing:

- At the start only accept once [+-]
- After the point one, only accept [0-9]
- "end" the string (cannot accept more text)

So far this is my code but isn't working(Only accepts numbers and no spaces)

```
if (y.matches("[a-zA-Z]" ) || x.trim().length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("You only can add numbers, no spaces and no special characters");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

After that i convert them to double(a,b,c,) and to this

```
double x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
```

Output: NaN

Any help or tips?
Thank You

If You require the full code i'll update the post

**Update:**
<strike>If i remove "-b" it gives a numeric result but i use sout to print b and it gives a number, probably the "-" is causing the problem</strike>
Fixed.

Comment: My guess : the code that read the variable `a` fails, resulting in a division by zero. Can you show us the code that reads the params?

Comment: "Only accepts numbers and no spaces" And punctuation and non-printing characters, and accented characters, and...

Comment: Actually, *not every* quadratic equation has a solution. Are you sure you are trying solvable one?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky Yeah i used a website which resolves this equations and the input i give are the same and(well before it started to say Nan) were correct.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Let me check separating in the x1 and x2 equation and i update the answer

Comment: If you’re using a Scanner, you should use its [nextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) method instead of next().  Then you won’t have to analyze the input yourself.